# Fitting time varying cox model in r

Tags: r, cox-regression

Please, I have been having some challenges trying to fit a time varying cox model. Precisely I find it hard getting the same result after following examples I read about in which the survSplit command was used. I end up with one error or the other, here is an example and the error message.

```
hip2=survSplit(Surv(Time,status)~Operation.Performed,
           data=hip,cut=c(200,500,1000,1600),
           end='Time',event='status',start="start")

Error in survSplit(Surv(Time, status) ~ Operation.Performed, data = hip,  : 
start time must be < stop time
```

Note: My data set initially has no column labelled start. But I read it will be created by the command, I do not know if this is right?

Please, is there anything am not doing correctly to get the right result??? or better still is there a better way to implement the survSplit command?

Comment: did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your data `head(hip)`, but the error message states that you have the start and end times confused - you can see the message in the code in github [here](https://github.com/cran/survival/blob/master/R/survSplit.R). `survSplit` Indeed creates a start time if you don't have one and calls it `"tstart"` by default. Unless you use an old version of the package, don't use the `event` And `start` Arguments as they are deprecated and for legacy use alone. Give a name to the `episode` for use in the co ph model as an interaction, and you *should* be OK.

```
hip2 <- survSplit(Surv(Time, status) ~., data=hip, cut=c(200,500,1000,1600),episode="tgroup")

model.coxph <- coxph(Surv(tstart, Time, status) ~ Operation.Performed:strata(tgroup), data=hip2)
```

And that should do it.